# Sql minus with joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Im bit stuck with a scenario like this I have two tables which named `messages` and `message_fields`

which has relation like this `message_fields` holds message_id and using that I can get the `name` of the message and I m trying to compare two Scemas same table like this

> ```
> select Message_id,field_id from DB1.MESSAGE_FIELDS a minus select
> Message_id,field_id from DB2.MESSAGE_FIELDS
> ```

But for this I need to know the `name` as well I know that I can put display name inside the select in both queires, but I dont want to minus the `name`  without affecting to the current query how can I get the Db1.message name for particulate `message_id`

I tried with INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOINS But didnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
with mf as (
      select Message_id,field_id from DB1.MESSAGE_FIELDS a
      minus
      select Message_id,field_id from DB2.MESSAGE_FIELDS
     )
select mf.*, m.name
from mf join
     messages m
     on mf.message_id = m.message_id;
```

Comment: that database must be one big mf

Comment: Woooooooo thnx a lot yeas this worked fine.. Thanx thanx thanx

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know oracle. This seem to strange code from my (mysql) platform.  what actually do `with` clause in this reason. can you explain me?  what you do if this server is mysql ?

Comment: @imran . . . The `with` clause defines a *common table expression* (CTE).  This is supported by most databases (but not MySQL).